# In general, what does an object need to have in order to be an iterator?

Tags: python

In general, what does an object need to have in order to be an iterator? Programmatically, what does class need to have in Python to be used as an iterator?

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement `__iter__()`, which should return an iterator object. The iterator object should implement `next()`, which will raise a `StopIteration` exception on iteration completion.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types